# How do you ActiveRecord query caching at the application level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

ActiveRecord query caching is enabled when a controller's action is invoked.  I also know that you can do something like this to temporarily enable caching for a given Model for a given code block:

```
User.cache do  
    ....
end
```

But is there a way to enable query caching for other contexts (e.g. when a script is run under the rails environment using ./script/runner)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ActiveRecord query cache lives only for the duration of a particular action (i.e. request). If you want a cached object to survive longer or be used between processes you need to look at something like memcached.

Answer (score 0):

[This plugin](http://github.com/ferblape/query_memcached) will persist the query cache using memcached.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to wrap the code given to `script/runner` in a block, directly on the commandline:

```
script/runner "User.cache { ... }"
```

Notice the caching is not simply for the `User` model, but for all queries performed within the codeblock.

Answer (score 0):

To get query caching when running a script you need to wrap any code with:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.cache do
  your_code_here
end
```

It looks like rails automatically sets the query cache for normal calls to Actions, but you have to do it manually in other contexts.